# can webpack output separate script and module files for browser and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, webpack

I am using webpack to make a JavaScript object that can be loaded by the browser (in a script tag) but I also want webpack to make a module that can be loaded by node (which needs `module.exports =` ).

Is there a way to get webpack to make two files; e.g. a `project.js` and `project.node.js`? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

The D3 JavaScript library seems to be doing something like this based on its `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "build/d3.node.js",
  "browser": "build/d3.js",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to get webpack to make multiple files [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189) - basically just export an array of objects rather than just one in the `webpack.config.js`.

Below is the `webpack.config.js` where I am making multiple files using the same entry point `main.js`.

```
module.exports = [
  {
      entry: './src/main.js',
      output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'my_project.js',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'my_project'
      },
      ... 
  },
  {
      entry: './src/main.js',
      output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'my_project.node.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        library: 'my_project'
      }
      ...
];
```

I am making two files: 1) `my_project.js` with `libraryTarget` set to `var` so that the it can be loaded by the browser using a script tag and 2) `my_project.node.js` with `libraryTarget` set to `commonjs2` so that node can load it.

I put `my_project.node.js` under `main` in the `package.json` so that webpack would load it - see below:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "something ...",
  "main": "my_project.node.js",
  ... 
}
```