# Loading different module for Webpack than Server Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

The best way I can think to explain my question is with an example:

Say I have a small single page app with server side rendering. On the client side new page requests resolve using XHR, but on the server I'd like to just run the server-side resolvers directly.

The components of the front end call a getter on a data object eg: `Data.page.get()` which either polls the server or returns a locally stored value. So I want webpack to pack the relevant client code. But I want to point to a different Data object on the server that calls whatever logic the server uses to resolve the XHR request, be it a db call or a filesystem call or whatever.

At the moment I've got `var Data = require(./data)` getting the server logic. Is there a way to tell webpack 'Hey, don't use `./data` here use `./data-client` instead? Or am I going about this backwards somehow?

This seems like a pretty simple concept but I'm still pretty new to javascript and programming in general and I'm a little stumped as to the best way to do it.

Or should I be processing the node script with webpack too like described here: [can webpack output separate script and module files for browser and node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644238/can-webpack-output-separate-script-and-module-files-for-browser-and-node)

I'm currently using webpack 1, but happy to solve the problem using webpack 2 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be fairly simple.

Webpack resolves modules with an extension priority:
1) .webpack.js
2) .web.js
3) .js

So in my case `require('./data') will resolve to`data.js`with node, and so long as I have a`data.web.js` it will resolve to that in webpack.

At least to my understanding.